# Where can I find tsconfig.json file in my react native project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

I am getting this message 
"Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-geocode'."
SO I am trying to modify tsconfig.json but could not find where it is

Comment: Does your editor support filename searching? If so, you can just search for the filename.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your root of project folder you can have tsconfig.json

if you dont have then create one as below screenshot

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/typescript

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Inside your root of project folder you can have tsconfig.json