# Can't resolve 'url' in node_modules error when trying to access Azure Key Vault with React

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm new to React and Azure, I'm trying to get a secret value from Azure [Key Vault]. I'm getting this compile error.

I'm using: "@azure/identity": "^2.0.4", "@azure/keyvault-secrets": "^4.4.0"

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SecretClient } from "@azure/keyvault-secrets";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

export const KV = () => {
    const [secret, setSecret] = useState("");
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const client = new SecretClient("https://xxx.vault.azure.net/", credential);
    client.getSecret("secretKey").then(res => { setSecret(res); });
    return <>{secret}</>
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@azure/keyvault-secrets/dist-esm/keyvault-common/src/parseKeyvaultIdentifier.js
> 3:0-27 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in
> 'xxx\node_modules@azure\keyvault-secrets\dist-esm\keyvault-common\src'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it. If you want to
> include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
> - install 'url' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

Comment: I found this post talking about the same error, https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/10498 but their proposed solution is to <Add "lib": ["dom"] to your tsconfig.json, or simply add dom to an existing array in the lib property>, but I'm not using typescript. How do I do this in react?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @Aoguye no, I don't think I did... moved to a different project so I don't really remember anymore lol

Answer (score 1):

> <Add "lib": ["dom"] to your tsconfig.json, or simply add dom to an existing array in the lib property>, but I'm not using typescript. How do I do this in react?

You can find `tsconfig.json` inside the root folder of your react project.

If you don't have `tsconfig.json`, you can create the same and add `"lib":["dom"]` to it.

For example:

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.package",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationDir": "./types",
    "outDir": "./dist-esm",
    "lib": ["dom"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@azure/keyvault-secrets": ["./src/index"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "../keyvault-common/**/*.ts",
    "samples-dev/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

You can refer to [Where can I find tsconfig.json file in my react native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220648/where-can-i-find-tsconfig-json-file-in-my-react-native-project), [tsconfig.json](https://riptutorial.com/reactjs/example/29620/tsconfig-json) and [Cannot find name 'URL'](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/10498)

Comment: thanks for this, I tried it but nothing changed. maybe it will be helpful for others though.