# Cant't Resolve URL Azure Keyvault in React

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-keyvault

I am working on adding a secret key to my react app. When I import the dependencies I get this error

ERROR in ./node_modules/@azure/keyvault-secrets/dist-esm/keyvault-common/src/parseKeyvaultIdentifier.js 3:0-27
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@azure/keyvault-secrets/dist-esm/keyvault-common/src/parseKeyvaultIdentifier.js 3:0-27 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback
> 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }' - install 'url'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

***Webpack 5 is the main source of the issue. It doesn't preload the Node.js polyfill.***

To resolve this issue, try install `npm install url`, and add it into `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
      fallback: {
        url: require.resolve("url/")
      }
  }
  // ...
};
```

For reference :  [Resolve | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

---

Alternatively, Try to remove complete dependency tree and rebuild it using npm and react-scripts in a package. At least until I find a suitable solution, everything runs smoothly with json version 4.0.3.

And u can also fix this issue through

```js
npm audit fix --force
```

For reference :

[reactjs - Can't resolve 'url' in node_modules error when trying to access Azure Key Vault with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022635/cant-resolve-url-in-node-modules-error-when-trying-to-access-azure-key-vault)